# Wrong expansion of JSON-LD

Tags: json-ld

I'm learning to work with JSON-LD and I'm stuck on this problem. This is mine document...

```
{
"@context": {
    "dbr": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/",
    "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "italy": "dbr:Italy_national_football_team",
    "ita_player_base_url": "italy:/",
    "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/",
    "team": "foaf:Organization",
    "player": "foaf:Person",
    "player_of": {
        "@id": "foaf:member",
        "@type": "@id"
    },
    "plays_with": {
        "@id": "foaf:knows",
        "@type": "@id"
    },
    "name": {
        "@id": "foaf:name",
        "@type": "xsd:string"
    },
    "number": {
        "@id": "foaf:status",
        "@type": "xsd:positiveInteger"
    }
},
"@graph": [{
    "name": "Buffon",
    "number": "1",
    "@type": "player",
    "player_of": "italy",
    "@id": "ita_player_base_url:Buffon"
}, {
    "name": "Insigne",
    "number": "20",
    "@type": "player",
    "player_of": "italy",
    "@id": "ita_player_base_url:Insigne",
    "plays_with": "ita_player_base_url:Buffon"
}]}
```

Then if I paste it to a JSON-LD to GIF service (or to everything else) I get that the players are `"player_of":"domainOfTheValidator/italy"` instead of `"player_of":"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Italy_national_football_team"`
Why is this happening? Obviously if I put `"player_of": "dbr:Italy_national_football_team"` instead of `"player_of": "italy"` it works... I'm getting crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [compact IRI](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#compact-iris) consists of a prefix, followed by `:`, followed by a suffix.

With `"italy": "dbr:Italy_national_football_team"` you are defining the prefix (`italy`). When you want to use it in a value, you have to use the colon (`:`) followed by a suffix (which is empty in your case).

So instead of

```
"player_of": "italy",
```

you would have to use

```
"player_of": "italy:",
```

Comment: Side note: Are you aware that e.g. `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Italy_national_football_team/Buffon` does not exist? You probably mean `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Gianluigi_Buffon`.

Comment: Yeah, now I understood! Thank you so much, you made my day!